# Heroku upload JPG ERROR (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I recently tried to push to Heroku, altering only my image assets via: adding a jpg document. I'm getting all sorts of weird errors, now. Can y'all help with this?

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-06-14T01:03:45.686901 #395]  INFO -- : Writing     
               /tmp/build_.../public/assets/....jpg
```

...

```
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected 
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/
```

...

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/...git'
```

Comment: how about checking in from heroku website, and find the detailed error?

Comment: Actually, the problem was easily fixed! Before pushing to Heroku, just run:

rake db assets:precompile

or something of that nature . . . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

Comment: answer your question below, so that if any one else runs into the problem they will know the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was easily fixed! Before pushing to Heroku, just run: rake db assets:precompile or something of that nature . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .